# Threejs Change image at runtime

Tags: three.js

I'm showing a 3d obj and applying the texture as jpg.
but I want to change this image when I click on a button, it is possible and how could I do that?

```
var loader = new THREE.ImageLoader(manager);
loader.load('models/obj/dla/dla.jpg', function(image) {
    texture.image = image;
    texture.repeat.set(1,1);
    texture.needsUpdate = true;
});

// model
var loader = new THREE.OBJLoader(manager);
loader.load('models/obj/dla/dla.obj', function(object) {

  object.traverse(function(child) {

  if (child instanceof THREE.Mesh) {

    child.material.map = texture;

  }

});
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? It seems you're also missing some code where you define `texture`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you change the texture/map of a material, it is important to set `material.needsUpdate = true`.

> .needsUpdate : Boolean
>
> Specifies that the material needs to be updated at the WebGL level. Set it to true if you made changes that need to be reflected in WebGL.
>   This property is automatically set to true when instancing a new material.

Here is some code, how I would implement it. I would also use `TextureLoader`instead of `ImageLoader`.

```js
// init
var obj;
var objLoader = new THREE.OBJLoader(manager);
var textureLoader = new THREE.TextureLoader(manager);

// load model
objLoader.load('models/obj/dla/dla.obj', function(object) {

  obj = object;
  loadTexture('models/obj/dla/dla.jpg', obj)

});

// load texture
function loadTexture(path, object) {
  textureLoader.load(path, function(texture) {
    object.traverse(function(child) {

      if (child instanceof THREE.Mesh) {

        child.material.map = texture;
        child.material.needsUpdate = true;

      }

    });
  });
}

// onclick handler
function onClick() {
  loadTexture('models/obj/dla/anotherTexture.jpg', obj);
}
```

If you don't use the old texture anymore, you might want to dispose it from memory.

```
...
if (child.material.map) child.material.map.dispose();

child.material.map = texture;
child.material.needsUpdate = true;
...
```

Comment: This answer is incorrect. You do not need to recompile the shader by setting `material.needsUpdate = true;` to change the texture.

Comment: Hm, maybe I picked it up falsly. And in my code, it also works without `needsUpdate = true´, as I just tested it. But this means that other answers are also incorrect in this matter? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16066448/three-js-texture-image-update-at-runtime

Comment: `needsUpdate = true` needs to be set on the new texture, or on `material.map` after the new texture is assigned. But `TextureLoader` sets the `needsUpdate` flag for you.