# change a picture dynamically 360

Tags: javascript, three.js, html5-canvas

```
<div style="margin-bottom: 200px">  
    <a href="#" onclick="cambio()"> sdsadasdas</a>
</div>

<div id="container"></div>
<div id="info"> </div>
```

I have an image using `three.js` which I need to change dynamically by others when I click on a button

```
<!-- <script src="three.min.js"></script> -->
<script>
    var camera, scene, renderer;

    var texture_placeholder,
    isUserInteracting = false,
    onMouseDownMouseX = 0, onMouseDownMouseY = 0,
    lon = 0, onMouseDownLon = 0,
    lat = 0, onMouseDownLat = 0,
    phi = 0, theta = 0;

    var imagen='HabitacionPrincipal'
    init(imagen);

    function cambio(){
    //What would I need to place here to be able to make the change dynamically?

    }

    function init(imagen) {
        var container, mesh;
        container = document.getElementById( 'container' );
        camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1100 );
        camera.target = new THREE.Vector3( 0, 0, 0 );
        scene = new THREE.Scene();

        var geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry( 500, 60, 40 );
        geometry.applyMatrix( new THREE.Matrix4().makeScale( -1, 1, 1 ) );

        console.log(imagen)
            var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {
                map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( imagen+'.jpg' )
            } );

        mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );    
        scene.add( mesh );

        renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
        renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
        container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

        window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false ); 
        animate();
    }
</script>
```

I need to change the image by a previously selected one

I tried this post but not sucessc

[Threejs Change image at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51079295/threejs-change-image-at-runtime)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make the variable globally accessible, instead of limiting its scope to the `init()` function.

Think of it as a Venn diagram, you have to place `material` outside `init()` and `cambio()` so that it's available to both. You can do this by declaring it on line 1:

```
var camera, scene, renderer, material;
```

Then, you can initialize `material` inside `init()` without using `var`:

```
function init(imagen) {
    // ...

    material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {
        map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( imagen+'.jpg' )
    } );

    // ...
}
```

Once you're  ready to call `cambio()`, the material will be globally available, so you can access it and change its map:

```
function cambio(){
    material.map = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( 'secondImage.jpg' );
}
```