# Theejs - Change texture on collada element with uses ShaderMaterial

Tags: three.js, collada, shadermaterial

So I have this Collada (dae) export from a 3d model application for creating packaging.

I've managed to import this model in my scene with

```
var loader = new THREE.ColladaLoader();
   loader.load("model.dae", collada => {

   this.scene.add(collada.dae);
});
```

This works. Animations do also work.

However this dae file has some references to external textures. And I want to programmaticly replace some of them.

The dea from an export uses `ShaderMaterial` elements and I have no idea to apply a new texture to it. Everything I do will make it black or does nothing.

**What I tried**

I know the name of the image texture that is beeing used that I want to replace. The name is `TextureResource129.png`.

So what I do:

- Load the new texture
- Loop through all nodes/children in the `dea` that is in the scene.
- I check if the node has a `material object` and `is a mesh`
- I clone the material
- I replace everywhere the old texture image is in the object tree by the new texture image. The export has them on 4 possible locations.
- Then I add the adjusted material again.
- Then the object turns black in the scene

The code:

```
var loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
loader.load("/assets/images/texture2/TextureResource129.png", texture => {
  this.dae.traverse(node => {
    if (node.material && node.isMesh) {
      if (
        node.material.uniforms.EnvDiff0 &&
        node.material.uniforms.EnvDiff0.value.image.currentSrc.indexOf("TextureResource129.png") > -1 ||
        node.material.uniforms.paperBump1 &&
        node.material.uniforms.paperBump1.value.image.currentSrc.indexOf("TextureResource129.png") > -1 ||
        node.material.uniforms.matDiff1 &&
        node.material.uniforms.matDiff1.value.image.currentSrc.indexOf("TextureResource129.png") > -1 ||
        node.material.uniforms.matDiff2 &&
        node.material.uniforms.matDiff2.value.image.currentSrc.indexOf("TextureResource129.png") > -1
      ) {
        var material = node.material.clone();
        if(material.uniforms.EnvDiff0) material.uniforms.EnvDiff0.image = texture;
        if(material.uniforms.paperBump1) material.uniforms.paperBump1.image = texture;
        if(material.uniforms.matDiff1) material.uniforms.matDiff1.image = texture;
        if(material.uniforms.matDiff2) material.uniforms.matDiff2.image = texture;
        node.material = material;
      }
    }
  });
});
```

This makes the object black. So `I tried only cloning the material and attaching it again to the same node`, without changes.
But even then it also turns black again:

```
var loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
loader.load("/assets/images/texture2/TextureResource129.png", texture => {
  this.dae.traverse(node => {
    if (node.material && node.isMesh) {
      if (
        node.material.uniforms.EnvDiff0 &&
        node.material.uniforms.EnvDiff0.value.image.currentSrc.indexOf("TextureResource129.png") > -1 ||
        node.material.uniforms.paperBump1 &&
        node.material.uniforms.paperBump1.value.image.currentSrc.indexOf("TextureResource129.png") > -1 ||
        node.material.uniforms.matDiff1 &&
        node.material.uniforms.matDiff1.value.image.currentSrc.indexOf("TextureResource129.png") > -1 ||
        node.material.uniforms.matDiff2 &&
        node.material.uniforms.matDiff2.value.image.currentSrc.indexOf("TextureResource129.png") > -1
      ) {
        var material = node.material.clone();
        node.material = material;
      }
    }
  });
});
```

So the question is:

***How can I change the texture of a collada (.dea) file programatic when it is in the scene?***

Comment: Are you using latest [ColladaLoader](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/examples/js/loaders/ColladaLoader.js) version? I don't see any mentions of "ShaderMaterial" in the entire loader, also I'm fairly sure `collada.scene` contains the scene not `collada.dae`. If I'm missing something, please disregard.

Comment: If you replace a material's texture, you also have to set `Material.needsUpdate` to `true`, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16066448/three-js-texture-image-update-at-runtime